# Protobuf Java - Merge Repeated Field by Unique ID

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a proto with a repeated field that is a message with a unique id and some details.  Simple example:

```
message Info
{
    message Details
    {
        string unique_id = 1;
        string detail_1 = 2;
        string detail_2 = 3;
        string detail_3 = 4;

    }

    repeated Details details = 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, detail 2 and 3 come from different sources.  The id, obviously, is the same when the object is the same.

I'm loading this data from text files doing a TextFormat.merge on the Info.builder twice, once for each file.  Unsurprisingly, when I do do this, I get twice as many detail entires as I want, with detail 3 filled in on half, and detail 1 and 2 filled in on half.

Is there a way to automatically merge this repeated field joining on ID and filling in the details accordingly, or do I just need to handle this by writing some code on my own?

Comment: I never found a way to have protobuf do this, ended up writing code that merges details if an object with that ID already exists during load.